# Pytorch: How to know if GPU memory being utilised is actually needed or is there a memory leak

Tags: memory-leaks, deep-learning, pytorch, gpu, conv-neural-network

I have 3 Tesla V100(16 GB). I am doing transfer learning using efficeint net (63 Million parameters) on images of (512,512) with a batch size of 20.
My GPU memory utilisation is below -
[image]

As you can see, it has almost filled up all the 3 GPUs(almost 80%).
My question is is there any theoretical way of calculating that the utilisation of GPU memory being shown is what is required by the model at a certain image and batch size or is there a memory leak in my GPU?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that is what you asked for but have you tried doing something like:

memory_usage = number_of_variables * memory_usage_per_variable.

So if you use `torch.float32` tensors, and you have 125 000 variables sent to the GPU with `.cuda()`. Then you are using 4Gbytes of memory on your GPU. You can compare with how much memory you have available on your memory.

Another Sanity check would be to check memory usage on the GPU's per iteration your model, if it doubles then you have a memory leak.

Hope this helps.

Comment: A question: How to know the number of variables in my code. Also, regarding the second part of the answer - In my case, memory size increases for the first epoch as you can see in the graph and then it remains the same for every other epoch.

Comment: Just look into the size of your tensors and there datatype, prefer float32 tensors as they take less memory. Since you have 63 million parameters, I presume it takes a lot of memory and a memory leak would crash your machine right away. The behaviour with the epochs is what I expect. So it seems ok, but what happens at 14 minutes ? Maybe you start the validation loop ?

Comment: Yes, validation loop gets started. I come across this article, I need some time to wrap my head around it https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/12649/how-to-calculate-the-mini-batch-memory-impact-when-training-deep-learning-models,